# Python Pandas xlsxwriter failing to close

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am building automation for Excel a multi-tabbed excel document. When I try to close the document I get the error below (full traceback, minus the personal details at the top), which then is corrupted and I cannot open the xlsx document. Unfortunately I haven't found any clues to go off of. I am using xlsxwriter functions to set row and column formatting, from what I've found this could be an issue but I haven't been able to track it down. Any thoughts on possible solutions?

```
writer.close()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1480, in close
    self._save()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlsxwriter.py", line 244, in _save
    self.book.close()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 324, in close
    self._store_workbook()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 709, in _store_workbook
    xml_files = packager._create_package()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xlsxwriter/packager.py", line 137, in _create_package
    self._write_worksheet_files()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xlsxwriter/packager.py", line 193, in _write_worksheet_files
    worksheet._assemble_xml_file()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 4221, in _assemble_xml_file
    self._write_cols()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 5807, in _write_cols
    self._write_col_info(self.colinfo[col])
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 5836, in _write_col_info
    if width > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Format' and 'int'
```

Comment: It looks like the code has a `set_column(first_col, last_col, width, cell_format, options)` method call with the `cell_format` and `width` in the wrong places.

Comment: @jmcnamara Thank you! I searched through my code and found exactly what you were mentioning. You are a life saver! :D